# Alias name for ip address

Tags: dns, webserver, hostname, apache-httpd

I have a website which is hosted in local Server (CentOS 5.x) (Hostname: xxx.yyy.local, IP : 192.168.5.25). I can browse the site typing the server IP address in the browser from my Local Network e.g: http://192.168.5.25/support

How can I get an alias for http://192.168.5.25/support Eg: http://mycompany/support ?

Note this is required for Internal network only. I don't want to access this site outside of my network.

Comment: Change it in your hosts file, usually in etc/hosts, if its just on that server. If you want it over the entire local network  [this](http://superuser.com/questions/402194/can-a-router-map-a-url-to-a-local-ip) may be helpful

Comment: Aren't you missing a slash in your example, or do you really mean to combine the IP address and `/support` into domain name `mycompanysupport`?

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions to multiple sites (http://serverfault.com/questions/700893/how-to-alias-name-for-ip-address).

Answer (score 6):

The "proper" way to do this would be to add a CNAME record on your local DNS server (that's what handles the conversion from hostnames like "mycompany" to IP addresses like 192.168.5.25). That way, you could point all DNS queries for "mycompany" to "xxx.yyy.local" (assuming "xxx.yyy.local" actually has a valid DNS A record pointing to 192.168.5.25 -- if it doesn't, just create one).

If your local DNS server doesn't allow you to add arbitrary DNS records (like most home routers would), you can still create local overrides for lookups for "mycompany" by adding the following line to `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.5.25 mycompany
```

Don't forget to add this on all systems that need to be able to access the website as `http://mycompany` in addition to `http://192.168.5.25`.